# "is not a function" error with a function on an anchor tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried to get the function inside the anchor to return the respective number of the pagination in react, but it doesn't work, I don't really understand why I copied a code from a course and it goes to him and not to me. would anyone know how to help me?
it gives me **"pagination.jsx:16 Uncaught TypeError: onPageChange is not a function
at onClick (pagination.jsx:16:1)"** in the onClick function.

```js
const Pagination = (props) => {
  const { itemsCount, pageSize, currentPage, onPageChange } = props;

  const pagesCount = Math.ceil(itemsCount / pageSize);
  if (pagesCount === 1) return null;
  const pages = _.range(1, pagesCount + 1);

return (
    <nav>
      <ul className="pagination">
        {pages.map((page) => (
          <li key={page} className="page-item">
            <a className="page-link" onClick={() => onPageChange(page)}>
              {page}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

Comment: What specifically "is not a function"?  Is the error telling you that `onPageChange` is not a function?  Then what is it and why do you expect it to be a function?  Or is the error telling you that `.map()` is not a function on `pages`?  Or something else?  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem and indicate the complete and specific error message.

Comment: Please add the definition of `onPageChange` to your question.

Comment: Add the definition for the `onPageChange` function, and the full error message in your question please.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check what's in `onPageChange` variable. Seems like it's not a function, it might be even `undefined`.
Try checking it before return with console.log.

Comment: I edited the post with the whole class. thanks for answer

Comment: try adding console log to check what's in `onPageChange`, like this
`const Pagination = (props) => {
  const { itemsCount, pageSize, currentPage, onPageChange } = props;
  console.log('onPageChange:', onPageChange);`